# Add style for displayName in DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code DataAnnotations in entityframework like this

```
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Description (*Mandatory)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description required")]
```

So name will be Description (*Mandatory),
Can i apply CSS style make text "Mandatory" in red in code behide?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style attribute in ValidationMessageFor method in a razor view

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Description, "", new { @style="color:red" })
```

Comment: I need only Display Name  is this case  text Mandatory.
Your answer is validate the field not relate to my question